# unable to load achievement screen in game center

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I want to load achievement screen in my gamecenter. The GKAchievement completeHandler is returing blank array of achievement and so Error is coming

"Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server." UserInfo=0xae232f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xae2f9b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. status = 5044, Game does not support achievements", NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.}

And achievement screen is showing "unable to load achievement". What is cause of this error?

Comment: Have you enabled Game Center for this app via iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue even after enabling the application in iTunesConnect. My problem was that I was authenticating the user in the AppDidFinishLaunching callback. Try moving this call forward to after the app launches and it should clear it up if you are having the same issue that I did.